# Creating bitmap fonts with just text editor?

Tags: fonts, file-format, bitmaps

I'd like to design a few icons for my window manager. For this purpose, I'd like to use bitmap fonts such as [siji](https://github.com/gstk/siji) (which is too small for my needs, unfortunately):

[image]

But instead of using large software such as fontforge or whatnot, I'd like to use just my text editor, [like I can do for images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap#XPM2) (call me dinosaur.)

Is there any font file format that supports editing by hand? Or do you know if there are any scripts that convert text specification to other formats? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts for the X Window System can be converted from `bdf` ([Bitmap Distribution Format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bdf/egff.htm)), which is human-readable.  It has been around a while (see [this from 1993](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/5005.BDF_Spec.pdf)).  However, the "readable" aspect is hexadecimal numbers.  As you pointed out, there are more readable *image* formats such as xbm and xpm — but apparently no use of those for fonts.

There are a few simple programs which edit bdf fonts, e.g., [bdfedit](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/bdfedit.html).

Alternatively, you could convert to/from a readable form with [bdf2c](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bdf2c/)